# Multiple Parameters in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I have created a crystal report layout with 3 parameter.

The 3 parameters are
1.) Date range
2.) Supplier
3.) Location code

User will always give input to the date range but will select either of these remaining two parameters based on the usage.

Is it possible to configure in one single report with optional option in Crystal layout

Comment: You mean the parameters are optional? Just pass an empty value.

Comment: Empty value.. How

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not using a very old version of Crystal, when you create or edit a parameter, look at the list of parameter properties: one of them is 'Optional Prompt' -- simply change it from the default of False to True.

Then, in your record select logic you can use the HasValue() function to check whether the user provided a value for that parameter.

Comment: I am using the latest version of crystal report.. Hasvalue() function???

Comment: How to use Hasvalue() function